# Compare two dataframes and write the differences to another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes. df1 and df2

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
'Buyer': ['Carl', 'Alex', 'Lauren'],
'Quantity': [18, 3, 8]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
'Buyer': ['Carl', 'Alex', 'Maya', 'Emily'],
'Quantity': [18, 3, 5, 5]})
```

I was wondering if there was a way to compare df1 with df2 and append whatver is in not df1 to df2 so I will have an end result like

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
'Buyer': ['Carl', 'Alex', 'Maya', 'Emily', 'Lauren'],
'Quantity': [18, 3, 5, 5, 8]})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to concat the two dfs and then drop dupes

```
df2 = pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates()

>>> df2
    Buyer  Quantity
0    Carl        18
1    Alex         3
2  Lauren         8
2    Maya         5
3   Emily         5
```

Answer (score 3):

Combine them like you said (`append`) and then just do a drop duplicate:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
'Buyer': ['Carl', 'Alex', 'Lauren'],
'Quantity': [18, 3, 8]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
'Buyer': ['Carl', 'Alex', 'Maya', 'Emily'],
'Quantity': [18, 3, 5, 5]})

df = df1.append(df2)

df = df.drop_duplicates()

print(df)
```

output:

```
    Buyer  Quantity
0    Carl        18
1    Alex         3
2    Maya         5
3   Emily         5
4  Lauren         8
```

Comment: Its better to have one statement like `df = df1.append(df2).drop_duplicates()`.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) it can be achieved.

```
res = pd.merge(df2,df1,on=['Buyer','Quantity'],how='outer')
```

output:

```
Buyer   Quantity
0   Carl    18
1   Alex    3
2   Maya    5
3   Emily   5
4   Lauren  8
```